# SQLiteConstraintException thrown when trying to insert

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, insert

I searched and searched and haven't found a solution for this. Hopefully someone here can help.

I'm trying to insert a custom ringtone into MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.
Most of the time it works great, but once in a while I get SQLiteConstraintException thrown when calling getContentResolver().insert(). The exception is thrown because a record with a unique column (_data) already exists for a particular value in that table.
However, when I then try to get that record using _data as the where clause, null is returned.

So it seems to me that there are multiple tables being checked here and the record with the existing identical _data column is some sort of associated table to the one I'm actually working with when using MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.

So, my question is, if this is the case, is there a way to clear out these orphaned records?
Or is there a way to determine which table this duplicate value is in so that I can manually delete it?
Maybe a files table of some type?

Also, maybe I'm completely wrong in my assumptions.
Any help is really appreciated.

Here's the code that saves the ringtone

```
ContentValues mediaValues = new ContentValues();
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filename.toString());
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, speakTextTxt);
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, speakTextTxt);
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg3");
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, filename.length());
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, appName);
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
mediaValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

ringtoneUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, mediaValues);
```

In the above `ringtoneUri` is null when this issue occurs.

Here's the Exception being thrown

```
03-04 13:18:16.522  24774-23075/? E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Error inserting bucket_id=1420360973 media_type=2 storage_id=65537 date_modified=1393450056 is_alarm=true is_ringtone=true parent=22388 format=12297 artist_id=90 is_music=false bucket_display_name=Ringtones album_id=161 title=German gorilla is_notification=true title_key=    3   /   I   ?   '   A      3   C   I   7   =   =   '    mime_type=audio/mpeg3 date_added=1393967896 _display_name=German_gorilladeuDEUcomgoogleandroidtts-75868.mp3 _size=32044 _data=/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.twoclaw.typeyourringtonepro/files/Ringtones/German_gorilladeuDEUcomgoogleandroidtts-75868.mp3
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column _data is not unique (code 19)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertFile(MediaProvider.java:3199)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insertInternal(MediaProvider.java:3439)
        at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.insert(MediaProvider.java:2851)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:220)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:156)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

I can't see anything that's different with the ones that fail, except that maybe they were already partially inserted at some point.

Trying to get that record then comes back empty

```
String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID};
String[] selectionArgs = {filename.toString()};
Cursor existingTone = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA+"=?", selectionArgs, null);
```

`if (existingTone.getCount() > 0)...` is false after that

The file does exist in the location shown in the _data column

Hopefully that explains things.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess I stumped everyone:) I've put in a work around for now but am still trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 1):

> "Maybe a files table of some type?"

You were so close! [MediaStore.Files](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.html) is exactly what you're looking for. You'll find that Android has indexed **everything** on the SD card (even `.nomedia` directories, which is totally unintuitive). Attempting to reinsert a record will result in the `SQLiteContraintException` (I think only on API level 19, since the uniqueness of `_data` wasn't always required). Also note that `MediaStore.Files` is new in API level 11.

**NOTE:** There's a simpler option, and that is [MediaScannerConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html), but I haven't used it so I'm unsure of how the performance compares to directly adding it to the MediaStore.

Anyway, I have to support all the way down to API level 7, so this is how I'm solving it:

```
Uri findAudioFileUri(File filename) {
    // SDK 11+ has the Files store, which already indexed... everything
    // We need the file's URI though, so we'll be forced to query
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        Uri uri = null;

        Uri filesUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE};
        String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = ?";
        String[] args = {filename.getAbsolutePath()};
        Cursor c = ctx.getContentResolver().query(filesUri, projection, selection, args, null);

        // We expect a single unique record to be returned, since _data is unique
        if (c.getCount() == 1) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            long rowId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
            String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));
            c.close();
            uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external", rowId);

            // Since all this stuff was added automatically, it might not have the metadata you want,
            // like Title, or Artist, or IsRingtone
            if (!title.equals(DESIRED_TITLE)) {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, DESIRED_TITLE);

                if (ctx.getContentResolver().update(toneUri, values, null, null) != 1) {
                    throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // update failed
                }

                // Apparently this is best practice, although I have no idea what the Media Scanner
                // does with the new data
                ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, toneUri));
            }
        }
        else if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            // I suppose the MediaScanner hasn't run yet, we'll insert it
            ... ommitted
        }
        else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); // it's expected to be unique!
        }

        return uri;
    }
    // For the legacy way, I'm assuming that the file we're working with is in a .nomedia
    // folder, so we are the ones who created it in the MediaStore. If this isn't the case,
    // consider querying for it and updating the existing record. You should store the URIs
    // you create in case you need to delete them from the MediaStore, otherwise you're a
    // litter bug :P
    else {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, path.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, path.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, path.getName());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, DESIRED_TITLE);
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, appName);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri newToneUri = ctx.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        // Apparently this is best practice, although I have no idea what the Media Scanner
        // does with the new data
        ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, newToneUri));

        return newToneUri;
    }
}
```

Comment: This part of the code ctx.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, toneUri)); never works if the file is no the external sdcard. works if it is on the internal sdcard.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution suitable for me. It works at all devices I've tested, even android 4.3 (API 19).
In order to avoid "column _data is not unique (code 19)" issue, much better perform delete row and insert it again. It used for Video and Audio file separately. Here is my code:

```
                if(gd.getContentType() == ContentType.Video){
                    ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.TITLE, filename);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Video.VideoColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                                 System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/"+fileext);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, gd.url);
                        Uri uri2 = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);


                        Log.i(TAG, "=refresh scan new file inserted video uri="+uri2);
                        if(uri2 != null){
                            uri_video = uri2;
                            //context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri_video));
                        }else{

                            Uri filesUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
                            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE};
                            String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = ?";
                            String[] args = {gd.url};
                            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(filesUri, projection, selection, args, null);

                            // We expect a single unique record to be returned, since _data is unique
                            if (c.getCount() == 1) {
                                c.moveToFirst();
                                long rowId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));
                                c.close();
                                uri2 = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external", rowId);
                                Log.i(TAG, "=refresh scan force uri2="+uri2);

                                if(uri2 != null){
                                    //context.getContentResolver().update(uri2, content, null, null);
                                    context.getContentResolver().delete(uri2, null, null);
                                    uri2 = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);
                                    if(uri2 != null){
                                        uri_video = uri2; 
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                }else{
                    ContentValues content = new ContentValues(4);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE, "audio"+filename);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATE_ADDED,
                                 System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/"+fileext);
                        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, gd.url);
                        Uri uri2 = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);


                        Log.i(TAG, "=refresh scan new file inserted audio uri="+uri2);
                        if(uri2 != null){
                            uri_audio = uri2;
                            //context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri_audio));
                        }else{

                            Uri filesUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
                            String[] projection = {MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE};
                            String selection = MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + " = ?";
                            String[] args = {gd.url};
                            Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(filesUri, projection, selection, args, null);

                            // We expect a single unique record to be returned, since _data is unique
                            if (c.getCount() == 1) {
                                c.moveToFirst();
                                long rowId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID));
                                String title = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE));
                                c.close();
                                uri2 = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external", rowId);
                                Log.i(TAG, "=refresh scan force audio uri2="+uri2);

                                if(uri2 != null){
                                    //context.getContentResolver().update(uri2, content, null, null);
                                    context.getContentResolver().delete(uri2, null, null);
                                    uri2 = context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, content);
                                    if(uri2 != null){
                                        uri_audio = uri2; 
                                    }
                                }
                            }


                        }
                }
        if(uri_video != null)
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri_video));
        if(uri_audio != null)
            context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri_audio));
```